# Knot DNS as a slave DNS: will re-transfer, will not refresh

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I am trying to setup a Knot DNS as a slave DNS server to our master running on Windows 2019 (in this example on ip 192.168.77.1). I would like to keep "copies" of several internal zones on this slave in case the master becomes unavailable. The setup is:

KnotDNS 2.4.0. @ Debian 9

The configuration is:

```
server: 
listen: 0.0.0.0@53

acl:
  - id: notify_from_master
    address: 192.168.77.1
    action: notify

remote: 
  - id: master
    address: 10.234.77.1@53

zone: 
  - domain: int.example.com
    storage: /var/lib/knot/
    master: master
    acl: notify_from_master

log: 
  - target: stdout
    any: info
```

The challenge is that I can't refresh a zone

- either after notification from master

```
2019-09-02T12:17:46 info: [int.example.com.] notify, incoming, 192.168.77.1@55212: received, serial 395
2019-09-02T12:17:46 info: [int.example.com.] refresh, outgoing, 191.168.77.1@53: remote serial 395, zone is outdated
2019-09-02T12:17:46 warning: [int.example.com.] refresh, remote 'master' not usable
2019-09-02T12:17:46 error: [int.example.com.] refresh, failed (no usable master)
```

- or by calling `knotc zone-refresh int.example.com`

```
2019-09-02T12:39:57 info: [int.example.com.] control, received command 'zone-refresh'
2019-09-02T12:39:57 info: [int.example.com.] refresh, outgoing, 10.234.77.1@53: remote serial 397, zone is outdated
2019-09-02T12:40:07 warning: [int.example.com.] refresh, remote 'master' not usable
2019-09-02T12:40:07 error: [int.example.com.] refresh, failed (no usable master)
```

But I can re-transfer the zone successfully whenever I choose to! `knotc zone-retransfer int.example.com`

```
2019-09-02T12:41:32 info: [int.example.com.] control, received command 'zone-retransfer'
2019-09-02T12:41:32 info: [int.example.com.] AXFR, incoming, 192.168.77.1@53: starting
2019-09-02T12:41:32 info: [int.example.com.] AXFR, incoming, 192.168.77.1@53: finished, 0.00 seconds, 1 messages, 6382 bytes
2019-09-02T12:41:32 info: [int.example.com.] refresh, outgoing, 192.168.77.1@53: zone updated, serial 396 -> 397
2019-09-02T12:41:32 info: [int.example.com.] zone file updated, serial 396 -> 397
```

I am not an expert - actually, I am probably the direct opposite of one. Is refresh significantly different than re-transfer? Is it even possible to have Windows 2019 server as master and Knot as slave? Do I have a better option than having cron call ever so often `knotc zone-retransfer xxx`? That might work - but it seems clumsy at best :(

Comment: Did you remember to change the serial value when you changed the zone content at master?

Comment: Whenever I change record on the master (the windows server), the serial gets changed automatically and the master notifies the slave running on Knot DNS. In the first example the Knot DNS slave gets notified from Windows master that the serial has changed and that the slave should refresh. But it won't :(